# AppCompatv7 Android 5.0 issue

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am trying to upgrade a project to Android 5.0. During this I also upgraded the support library to version 21. As soon as I did this I had to upgrade the project to 5.0 to remove some errors. As soon as I did this there was an issue and the jar file was no longer being built. In the end I had to roll back to appcompat version 20.

Has anyone seen this and managed to get round this problem?

EDIT by Squonk:

I've been using appcompat-v7 for some time to provide ActionBar support (previously I'd used ActionBarSherlock) - everything had been working without problems. I don't update my dev tools regularly (I'm still using Kepler eclipse for example) and I only check Android SDK Manager every few months.

Last week I started SDK Manager and saw a whole load of revisions to existing SDK packages as well as the API 21 stuff so decided to update everything. I followed that by checking for eclipse updates (there were some and I updated those).

Initially I got over 100 errors in the Problems and Console panes then realised they all related to new /res features introduced with Android v5 - as I'd had appcompat-v7 setup already I realised it was targeting API 19 so adjusted it to target API 21, cleaned and rebuilt. At that point there were no errors showing in Problems or Console BUT the /bin directory was empty.

EDIT2 by Squonk...

I've now tried the following...

- Deleted the library appcompat-v7 project from eclipse
- Deleted the android-sdk-linux folder completely
- Downloaded a new copy of the Android SDK
- Ran SDK Manager and made sure everything was installed with the latest version / revision
- Used File -> Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace to create a new library project
- Built the project.

The result I'm now seeing is the library /bin folder has an empty /res folder and a copy of the AndroidManifest.xml. The actual build process failed with error...

```
Error executing aapt: Return code 132
android-support-v7-appcompat
line 1
Android ADT Problem
```

I've also tried Android Studio v1.0.1 and I'm seeing the same aapt error return code 132 so it seems aapt is obviously the root of the problem.

Comment: Show errors from yours logs.

Comment: There is no error to show. The .bin file was just not populated.

Comment: Did you `Check for Updates`, after upgrading the SDK?

Comment: @CliveJefferies : Other than rolling back to v20 did you find a solution for v21? I have the same empty /bin folder as you describe.

Comment: No. I still have not solved this.

Comment: @CliveJefferies : I've put a bounty on your question - let's see if someone has a solution.

Comment: @Squonk There are absolutely no build errors?

Comment: Are you using Gradle? What jar are you referring to? Can you please elaborate more about your problem?

Comment: @matiash : See the edit I've added to the question

Comment: @AssafGamliel : See the edit I've added to the question

Comment: @matiash : Can you explain further? As I said in my edit to the original question, the appcompat-v7 library project doesn't show any errors after I changed its build target to 21. What errors do you mean?

Comment: @Squonk Sorry, that last comment was due to a confusion (I had a corrupted SDK installation, now fixed, which contained an xml file with errors). Please disregard it.

Comment: @Squonk Is the bin folder for the appcompat_v7 project also empty?

Comment: @matiash : See EDIT2 I made to the original question. I'm currently looking into the aapt error code.

Comment: @CliveJefferies : What OS are you running? Windows, Mac, Linux ??? SO far Googling for the aapt error code I mention in the edits is related to 32-bit Ubuntu and Debian Linux - I'm using 32-bit Debian Wheezy.

Comment: @Squonk: Here is a directory full of working samples of `appcompat-v7`, all set up for Android Studio: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat Try those in Android Studio and see what you get. My guess is that you are not using the latest `buildToolsVersion`, as that determines what edition of **`aapt`** you would be using from Android Studio. My guess assumes that there is a bug that was fixed in **`aapt`**, of course.

Comment: @Commonsware : Many thanks. I'll try some and see what happens. I've juggled various versions of things including `buildToolsVersion` and my current test project for Android Studio *is* actually set for 21.1.2 but there are possibly inconsistencies with other files due to me blindly twiddling.

Comment: @CliveJefferies : But which OS? Windows, Mac, Linux? I'm curious, if you're using Linux of some sort then there may be a common problem although the link that Commonsware posted indicates his samples are for a linux dev platform. Research I've done suggested there may be a bug in one of the linux versions of the build tools - but I'm not sure.

Comment: IDE: Eclipse. OS: Mac OS 10.9.5. SDK tools: 23.0.5. Platform tools: 21. Build tools: 21.1.1. Support library 21.0.2. Java version: 1.7

Comment: Are you extending ActionBarActivity instead of Activity? If not, give it a try.

Did you check that your Manifest is using theme AppCompat and your target is API 21?

Comment: @joaquin : My code isn't an issue. The app has been out on Google Play for a long time now. The problem is with the build tools as a result of a recent update using SDK Manager - the result is the appcompat-v7 library no longer builds correctly with either Eclipse or Android Studio.

Comment: @squonk oh, my mistake then. Google updates had ruined several things. Im kinda an addict of updates but I promise I won't update ever again. I had to reinstall everything related to IDE with the last update because of Gradle exception and I lost a complete working day

Answer (score 1):

Now the new update of android studio fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I've updated to Android Studio v1.0.2 and my Android SDK shows everything is at the most recent version / revision.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the new version of AppCompat(v21) requires the target 21 and also, version 1.7 of JDK to run.

Check the version of the JDK that you are running.

Comment: I originally had OpenJDK v1.7 when I first encountered the problems in  Android Studio and Eclipse. When I started using Android Studio to see if I could fix the problem it warned me OpenJDK could be unstable so I installed Oracle JDK 1.8 but I still got exactly the same problems.

Comment: I am using both target 21 and JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

In Gradle build system, when I use AppCompat v7 version 21, I have to set buildTools Version to 21 too.
Not just target to SDK21 but buildTools too.

I not sure how to set it in Eclipse.

Comment: I see the same behaviour in Eclipse as I do with Android Studio. I've mostly been testing with Android Studio though and Commonsware pointed me at a link to appcompat-v7 projects which he assures me build fine for him but I've still got the same problem trying it with his projects.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with aapt on some 32 bit systems. It throws an error 132 on app:processDebugResources which is when aapt is 'crunching' png files ready for inclusion in the apk package. You can see more details at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75110

Can you just say if you are indeed running on a 32 bit processor, and if so which one? You can use lscpu to find out.

Comment: Hi, I gave up in the end and moved to Android studio. Thanks.

Comment: Actually my problem was in Android Studio so it's interesting it worked for you. I've FINALLY found a work-around at least which is insanely complex but at least allows me to work on my apps when away from home.